# Existe alguma forma mais bonita para eu trocar os índices?

Tags: c

Este é o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define tam 20

int main (void){
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    int num[tam];
    int troca[tam];
        for(int i = 0; i < tam; i ++){
            printf("\n\tDigite aqui o %dº número >==> ", i+1);
                scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        }
            for(int i = 0; i < tam; i ++){
            if(i == 10){
                printf("\n");
            }
                troca[0]=num[1];
                troca[2]=num[3];
                troca[4]=num[5];
                troca[6]=num[7];
                troca[8]=num[9];
                troca[10]=num[11];
                troca[12]=num[13];
                troca[14]=num[15];
                troca[16]=num[17];
                troca[18]=num[19];
                troca[19]=num[18];
                troca[17]=num[16];
                troca[15]=num[14];
                troca[13]=num[12];
                troca[11]=num[10];
                troca[9]=num[8];
                troca[7]=num[6];
                troca[5]=num[4];
                troca[3]=num[2];
                troca[1]=num[0];

            sleep(1);

            printf("\t%d", troca[i]);

        }
return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que deseja fazer, só o título da pergunta não esclarece o suficiente.

Comment: Existe, mas explique melhor qual é a sua necessidade editando a pergunta.

Comment: assim, eu desenhei um vetor de 20 posições, logo após isso eu tinha que inverter os valores de vetores da seguinte maneira. o primeiro valor com o segundo, o terceiro com o quarto, o quinto com o sexto e assim por diante até chegar na troca do décimo nono com o vigésimo.

Answer (score 3):

Que tal assim?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define tam 20

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    int num[tam];
    int troca[tam];
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("\n\tDigite aqui o %dº número >==> ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (i == 10) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tam; j += 2) {
            troca[j] = num[j + 1];
            troca[j + 1] = num[j];
        }
        sleep(1);
        printf("\t%d", troca[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Isso daí faz a troca no seu programa mais bonita e mais lógica. Apesar disso, não entendo qual é o propósito desse programa.

Ou melhor ainda, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define tam 20

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    int num[tam];
    int troca[tam];

    /* Lê todos os números. */
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("\n\tDigite aqui o %dº número >==> ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    /* Realiza as trocas. */
    for (int j = 0; j < tam; j += 2) {
        troca[j] = num[j + 1];
        troca[j + 1] = num[j];
    }

    /* Mostra o resultado. */
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
        printf("\t%d", troca[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mais corretamente, seria `for (int j = 0; j < tam; j += 2) { troca[j] = num[j + 1]; troca[j + 1] = num[j]; }`

Comment: @Wtrmute De acordo com o código original sim, mas claramente não é esse o propósito do autor da pergunta (embora eu não saiba qual seria).

Comment: nao fez as trocas com esse código, só retornou tudo 0 e -1, mas sim, dai por diante consigo resolver, agradeço desde já!

Comment: @fvsgamers Agora que você explicou o propósito do seu programa em um comentário na pergunta, eu fiz uma segunda versão e coloquei nesta resposta. Se isso resolver o seu problema, não esqueça de clicar no ✅ que aparece abaixo dos números de votação desta resposta para marcar esta pergunta como solucionada e marcar a minha resposta como sendo a solução.

Comment: @VictorStafusa: Pode não ser o propósito original do autor da pergunta, mas note que na sua resposta você lê os números para o vetor `num` e depois inverte os valores no vetor `troca` _que não foi inicializado_.

Comment: @Wtrmute Oh, bem notado. Obrigado.